# Do I endorse a direct rollover check?

Tags: united-states, 401k, rollover-direct

I had a 401(k) from a previous employer at Fidelity.  For some reason they won't send funds directly to another institution so they sent the check to me but made payable to

ETrade
FBO (My Name)

Do I need to endorse that before forwarding it to ETrade?  Guessing not since I am not the payee.  However, I don't want to send it to ETrade only to have it sent back because I was supposed to endorse it.

Answer (score 18, accepted):

A family member just went through that with a transfer from one 401(k) to another 401(k). The new one made it clear that the check wasn't to be signed by the person.

The new company should have in their instructions a section telling you what to do with the check. Look at the part of the instructions where they tell you how the check is to be made out. Because it was made payable to  "ETrade FBO (My Name)" that means "For the Benefit of", that would mean that you don't sign.  The new company should have a phone number or email address where you can ask for clarification.

Comment: I knew what FBO meant, that's why I thought I should NOT sign because I am not the payee.  Just wanted to hear if anyone had dealt with it specifically.  Much obliged!!!